# jquery easyslider bugs out after 12 images

Tags: jquery, css, easyslider

I'm using EasySlider w Jquery and when i add more than about 11 images in my UL and use the next/previous slider images it bugs out and slides to the first image really fast.

What can be causing this? see it here http://eminemforum.net/gallery/

```
<div id="content">
      <div id="slider">
        <ul>
<li><img src="img/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/6.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/7.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/8.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/9.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/10.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/11.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/15.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>



(function($) {

$.fn.easySlider = function(options){

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {            
        prevId:         'prevBtn',
        prevText:       'Previous',
        nextId:         'nextBtn',  
        nextText:       'Next',
        controlsShow:   true,
        controlsBefore: '',
        controlsAfter:  '', 
        controlsFade:   true,
        firstId:        'firstBtn',
        firstText:      'First',
        firstShow:      false,
        lastId:         'lastBtn',  
        lastText:       'Last',
        lastShow:       false,              
        vertical:       false,
        speed:          800,
        auto:           false,
        pause:          2000,
        continuous:     false, 
        numeric:        false,
        numericId:      'controls'
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

    this.each(function() {  
        var obj = $(this);              
        var s = $("li", obj).length;
        var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
        var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
        var clickable = true;
        obj.width(w); 
        obj.height(h); 
        obj.css("overflow","hidden");
        var ts = s-1;
        var t = 0;
        $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);          

        if(options.continuous){
            $("ul", obj).prepend($("ul li:last-child", obj).clone().css("margin-left","-"+ w +"px"));
            $("ul", obj).append($("ul li:nth-child(2)", obj).clone());
            $("ul", obj).css('width',(s+1)*w);
        };              

        if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css('float','left');

        if(options.controlsShow){
            var html = options.controlsBefore;              
            if(options.numeric){
                html += '<ol id="'+ options.numericId +'"></ol>';
            } else {
                if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
                html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
                html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
                if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';              
            };

            html += options.controlsAfter;                      
            $(obj).after(html);                                     
        };

        if(options.numeric){                                    
            for(var i=0;i<s;i++){                       
                $(document.createElement("li"))
                    .attr('id',options.numericId + (i+1))
                    .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ (i+1) +'</a>')
                    .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
                    .click(function(){                          
                        animate($("a",$(this)).attr('rel'),true);
                    });                                                 
            };                          
        } else {
            $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){     
                animate("next",true);
            });
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){     
                animate("prev",true);               
            }); 
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){        
                animate("first",true);
            });             
            $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){     
                animate("last",true);               
            });             
        };

        function setCurrent(i){
            i = parseInt(i)+1;
            $("li", "#" + options.numericId).removeClass("current");
            $("li#" + options.numericId + i).addClass("current");
        };

        function adjust(){
            if(t>ts) t=0;       
            if(t<0) t=ts;   
            if(!options.vertical) {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
            } else {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*h*-1));
            }
            clickable = true;
            if(options.numeric) setCurrent(t);
        };

        function animate(dir,clicked){
            if (clickable){
                clickable = false;
                var ot = t;             
                switch(dir){
                    case "next":
                        t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? t+1 : ts) : t+1;                       
                        break; 
                    case "prev":
                        t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? t-1 : 0) : t-1;
                        break; 
                    case "first":
                        t = 0;
                        break; 
                    case "last":
                        t = ts;
                        break; 
                    default:
                        t = dir;
                        break; 
                };  
                var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
                var speed = diff*options.speed;                     
                if(!options.vertical) {
                    p = (t*w*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginLeft: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );              
                } else {
                    p = (t*h*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginTop: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );                  
                };

                if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
                    if(t==ts){
                        $("a","#"+options.nextId).hide();
                        $("a","#"+options.lastId).hide();
                    } else {
                        $("a","#"+options.nextId).show();
                        $("a","#"+options.lastId).show();                   
                    };
                    if(t==0){
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();
                    } else {
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).show();
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).show();
                    };                  
                };              

                if(clicked) clearTimeout(timeout);
                if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        animate("next",false);
                    },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
                };

            };

        };
        // init
        var timeout;
        if(options.auto){;
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                animate("next",false);
            },options.pause);
        };      

        if(options.numeric) setCurrent(0);

        if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();              
        };              

    });

};
```

})(jQuery);

[code]

```
    /* image replacement */
        .graphic, #prevBtn, #nextBtn, #slider1prev, #slider1next{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-8000px;
    padding-left: 5px;
            }
    /* // image replacement */          
    #content{
    position:relative;
    /* [disabled]padding-bottom: 20px; */
    /* [disabled]background-color: #c8cfd5; */
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #fff;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
        }           

/* Easy Slider */

    #slider ul, #slider li,
    #slider2 ul, #slider2 li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
        }
    #slider2{
    margin-top:1em;
}
    #slider li, #slider2 li{
    /* 
            define width and height of list item (slide)
            entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
        */ 
    /*width:945px;*/
    width:940px;
    height:510px;
    overflow:hidden;
        }   
    #prevBtn, #nextBtn,
    #slider1next, #slider1prev{
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:77px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-40px;
    top:200px;
    z-index:1000;
        }   
    #nextBtn, #slider1next{
    left:940px;
        }                                                       
    #prevBtn a, #nextBtn a,
    #slider1next a, #slider1prev a{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:31px;
    height:77px;
    background:url(img/btn_prev.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
        }   
#shadows {
    height: 98px;
    position: reletive;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    bottom:20px;

}
.shadow1 {
    background-image: url(img/gallery_shadow-left.jpg);
    float: left;
    height: 98px;
    width: 130px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:147px;
    margin-left:-343px;
    z-index:1000;
}
#shadows .shadow2 {
    background-image: url(../img/gallery_shadow-right.jpg);
    display:block;
    width:98x;
    height:130px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-40px;
    top:200px;

}

    #nextBtn a, #slider1next a{ 
        background:url(img/btn_next.gif) no-repeat 0 0; 
        }   

    /* numeric controls */  

    ol#controls{
        margin:1em 0;
        padding:0;
        height:28px;    
        }
    ol#controls li{
        margin:0 10px 0 0; 
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        height:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        }
    ol#controls li a{
        float:left;
        height:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background:#DAF3F8;
        color:#555;
        padding:0 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
    ol#controls li.current a{
        background:#5DC9E1;
        color:#fff;
        }
    ol#controls li a:focus, #prevBtn a:focus, #nextBtn a:focus{outline:none;}

/* // Easy Slider */
```

Comment: From the demo, it looks to me like it's just scrolling back to the beginning, when you click "next" but you're at the last picture. This would be the `continuous` option at work, no? I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: @Matt Ball i've just tried removing [continuous] and setting it to false but even still it scrolls back to the first image or whatever.

Comment: Sorry it scrolls back to the image before the last one, but really fast

Comment: @tom: no, it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/FrYkc/. I'd guess your code is being cached so the browser didn't actually see your change ...are you using IE6 or something? I've been doing all this in Chrome with no issues, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have tried it in FF, Chrome and Safari still does the same thing. When you hit the last image use the previous button and it seems to scroll very fast to the second to last image.

Comment: @MattBall I have added more gallery images as you can see when you scroll through them they skip really fast http://jsfiddle.net/datastream/3eApp/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the plugin - at least, your copy of it - needs jQuery 1.3.2 (which is **very** out of date).

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/pUW5e/

Hooray for plugins that don't get updated when jQuery does.

Comment: Ahhhh how typical. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

After having investigated this issue, I believe the problem is not the JQuery version at all. I believe the problem is caused by very large values on `margin-left`. In my Firefox the issue appears at values around the 10,000 pixel mark.

So you'd have to modify the code to not just blindly increase the value all the time. Use a different way.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
        <ul class="slider clearfix">
            <li class="first">
                <img src="img1.jpg" width="300" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img2.jpg" width="400" height="450" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img3.jpg" width="500" height="550" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img4.jpg" width="450" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img5.jpg" width="350" height="550" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img3.jpg" width="400" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img4.jpg" width="250" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img4.jpg" width="250" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img4.jpg" width="250" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img4.jpg" width="250" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img4.jpg" width="250" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img4.jpg" width="250" height="350" />
            </li>
            <li class="last">
                <img src="img12.jpg" width="600" height="350" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" title="Prev" class="prev left">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" title="Next" class="nxt right">Next</a>
    </div>`


$(function(){


var cnt = 0;
  var liItems = $('.slider > li');
  var itemLen = liItems.length;



function getMaxLiWidth(){
   var maxWidth = 0;
     $(liItems).each(function(i){
    if(this.offsetWidth > maxWidth)
      maxWidth = this.offsetWidth + 30;
     });
     return maxWidth;
  }



if(itemLen > 1){
   $('.slider-wrapper').css('width', getMaxLiWidth());
  }
  $('.slider').css('width', getMaxLiWidth()*itemLen);
  $(liItems).css('width', getMaxLiWidth());
  var sliderWid = $('.slider > li').outerWidth();

  $('.prev').addClass('disable');

  $('.nxt').click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
    return
   }
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
   $('.prev').removeClass('disable');   
    $(this).removeClass('disable');
    cnt++;
    $('.slider').animate({'left': sliderWid * (-cnt)}, 500, function(){
     $('.nxt').removeClass('clicked');
     if( cnt == itemLen -1){
      $('.nxt').addClass('disable');
     }
    });
  });
  $('.prev').click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
    return
   }
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
   $('.nxt').removeClass('disable');   
    $(this).removeClass('disable');
    cnt--;
    $('.slider').animate({'left': sliderWid * (-cnt)}, 500, function(){
     $('.prev').removeClass('clicked');
     if( cnt == itemLen-8){
      $('.prev').addClass('disable');
     }
    }); 
  });
 });
```